# Display value of two-dimensional php array in table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array extracted from MySQL called "**$agents**", looking like:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [agent] => Agent/1002 [total] => 02:11:07 )
  [1] => Array ( [agent] => Agent/1400 [total] => 01:49:53 )
  [2] => Array ( [agent] => Agent/1500 [total] => 03:26:29 ) )
```

Then another MySQL query creates a table as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
    $result .="<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td align=center>".
      $row[1]."</td><td align=center>".
      $row[2]."</td><td align=center>".
      $row[3]."</td><td align=center>".$agents['0']['total']."</tr>";
}
```

How can I get the 'total' value from the array displayed in the last column of the table?
I want to insert the total for each agent. With an if statement, very simplified, like:

```
if $row[0] == $agents['0']['agent'] echo $agents['0']['total'] else echo 'NONE'"
```

Tried with "**foreach**" loop, but didn't get it to work.
Any ideas/suggestions of how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize a counter above the second fetching. Like this:

```
$agents = holds your first data fetches from db

$i = 0; // initialize a counter
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {

    // condition block
    if($row[0] == $agents[$i]['agent']) {
        $total = $agents[$i]['total']; // if they match, assign the total
    } else {
        $total = ''; // else just assign an empty string
    }

    $result .="
        <tr><td>".$row[0]."</td>
        <td align=center>".$row[1]."</td>
        <td align=center>".$row[2]."</td><td align=center>".$row[3]."</td>
        <td align=center>".$total."</tr>
    ";
    $i++; // increment
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, almost there I think. Changed if($row[0] == $agents[$i]['total']) to if($row[0] == $agents[$i]['agent']).  It fills up the total for the first result only, the other 3 rows get empty results for the "total" column.

Comment: with this correction it works, but just for the 1st row. Anything to do with the counter not increasing maybe?